# SQL: No two entities can have the same combination of two attributes?

Tags: sql, relational-database

For example, if I have a table "Delivery" with attributes date and driver. I want there to be no two deliveries that have the same driver on the same date. How would I do this in a CREATE TABLE statement?

Comment: That will depend on what RDBMS you're using. Please tag the question appropriately.

Comment: create a unique constraint or a unique index on those two columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you would declare either a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE INDEX over those two columns.  The more common case, in which the unique columns are considered to provide the identity of the item modelled by the row, is to declare a PRIMARY KEY.

Some people prefer to create a separate, auto-numbered INTEGER field to be the PRIMARY KEY and declare a UNIQUE INDEX on the two columns for which you want to enforce uniqueness.  This is called using a "surrogate" or "non-intelligent" key.  The first solution is called using a "natural" key.

There are minor variations in the syntax for creating these constraints depending on what database product you are using, but they are usually something like:

```
 ALTER TABLE table_name ADD PRIMARY KEY key_name (column_name1, column_name2)
```